# Unable to browse images on the CKEditor in the admin area

Tags: wordpress, civievent, ckeditor, kcfinder

When I try to browse and upload images on the CKEditor in the admin area I get the error below. Can someone give me a clue? See the screenshot. WordPress 4.6.1, CiviCRM 4.7.9

[image]

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed to locate civicrm.settings.php. Please boot with settingsFile, search, or CIVICRM_SETTINGS; or normalize your directory structure.' in /nas/content/staging/theexecnet/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php:125 Stack trace: 
#0 /nas/content/staging/theexecnet/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php(415): Civi\Cv\Bootstrap->boot() #1 /nas/content/staging/theexecnet/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/integration/civicrm.php(45): require_once('/nas/content/st...') 
#2 /nas/content/staging/theexecnet/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/integration/civicrm.php(140): checkAuthentication() 
#3 /nas/content/staging/theexecnet/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/core/bootstrap.php(39): require('/nas/content/st...') 
#4 /nas/content/staging/theexecnet/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/browse.php(15): require('/nas/content/st...') 
#5 {main} thrown in /nas/content/staging/theexecnet/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php on line 125
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked to see if your civicrm.settings.php file is still in-tact? See if it is there and then make sure it has the correct permissions. In Drupal sites, it lives in sites/default/civicrm.settings.php.

Edit: In Wordpress sites, it should be in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php

Comment: Yes it is in-tact, the rest of civicrm works.
"It should live in sites/default/civicrm.settings.php" - where is this in Wordpress? My  is civicrm.settings.php is located in wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php

Comment: It looks like your CiviCRM installation is non-standard, in that your codebase was either extracted to `/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/` instead of `/wp-content/plugins/`. This would result in your civicrm.settings.php being located in a `civicrm` directory inside another `civicrm` directory. Either that, or one of your settings is telling CiviCRM to look for the settings file in `/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm` even though it's where it's supposed to be. Please check your directory structure and let us know if you have a civicrm directory inside another civicrm directory in plugins.

Comment: Please see the screenshot if you see anything unusual in the civicrm location in Wordpress:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz1kxx0BuwdCZXpGcW1GZWt2YmM/view

What I had to do in order to fix it is - in wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php I had to specify the location of civicrm.settings.php - inside the definition of public static function singleton() {
self::$singleton = new Bootstrap(array('settingsFile'=>'/path/to/your/civicrm.settings.php'));
}